# stored procedure that counts value of columns with same id

Tags: sql, count, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to have a stored procedure that counts values based on id ?

UPDATE:
I want, columns with the same value in 'Day' have the same ID.
I want to count the number in one column, and also display the ID it'd correlate to.

my table

```
  | id   | day    | desc  |
   |:---- |:------:| ----- |
   | 1    |  mon   | Three |
   |:---- |:------:| ----- |
   | 1    |  mon   | Three |
   |:---- |:------:| -----:|
   | 2    | Tues   | Three |
   |:---- |:------:| -----:|
   | 2    | Tues   | Three |
   |:---- |:------:| -----:|
   | 3    | Weds   | Three |
   |:---- |:------:| -----:|
   | 3    | Weds   | Three |
   |:---- |:------:| -----:|
   | 2    |Tues    | Three |
   |:---- |:------:| -----:|
   | 2    | Tues   | Three |
```

desired output from sp :

```
   | id   | day    | desc |
   |:---- |:------:| -----|
   | 1    |  2     | Three|
   |:---- |:------:| -----|
   | 2    | 4      |Three |
   |:---- |:------:| -----|
   | 3    | 2      |Three |
   |:---- |:------:| -----|
```

[neer suggested I do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65197464/14401216)

```
select id, count(*) as cnt
from mytable
group by id
```

which is good for bringing back just one column but I now need to bring back two columns.

summary,
how do you count one column and return it with the corresponding ID's (where values of column A all have the same ID depending on value)

Comment: How this question is related to stored procedures? You are asking about query logic, not sp. Title and tag are misleading.

Comment: this query has to happen within a stored procedure, please see below of the answer.

Comment: Logic of this query does not depend on execution context - view, sp, function, ad-hoc etc. `stored-procedures` tag is intended to mark questions, which deal with sp specific problems (parameters, temp table scopes, access rights, syntax problems and many more). If someone searches for such sp centric problems, your question title and tag create just unwanted noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER :

```
SELECT ID, CAST(StartDate as Date) as StartDate, count(*) as Values
FROM 
Table
WHERE 
DateArchived is null
GROUP BY CAST(StartDate as Date), ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select id, count(*) as cnt
from mytable
group by id
```

The query itself should be sufficient - or you can use a view if you don't want to type the same query again and again.